# 照顾 vs 安慰 zhaogu vs anwei

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Anyone know the difference between these two verbs? Both seem to mean 'to care for'. Google image search seems to show more Mother/children/illness care for 照顾, but 安慰 also seems to be largely person based (as opposed to caring for a sofa by not leaving dirty plates on it!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

安慰 (anwei) is used for mental care, similar in meaning to "comfort/consolation". 
照顾 (zhaogu) is used for daily care, like that of parents towards kids, nanny towards a baby, nurse towards patients, etc.

Typical use:
他生气了，我安慰他。(He's upset, so I comfort him.)
他生病了，我照顾他。(He's sick, so I took care of him.)

Comment: Thanks guys - that's really clear now :-)

Comment: 安慰傷心的人(comfort sad people)；安撫生氣的人 (appease angry people)

Comment: Agree with the comments on this page, 安慰 is not *mentally care*, which in English sounds like a job given to caregivers in a psychiatric hospital. The rest of the answer is good.

Comment: As everyone said - 安慰 is simply to comfort, even a hug and a few nice words, but 照顾 is actual caring for, providing with things and help.

Answer (score 3):

• 安慰 = comfort

• 照顾 = to look after

---

Here’s *ABC*’s definition and sample sentence for 安慰

> comfort; console
>
> 安慰她几句。
>   Ānwèi ²tā jǐ jù.
>   Say a few words to comfort her.

Here’s *ABC*’s definition of 照顾:

> 1 look after; care for; attend to
>
> 2 consider; take into account
>
> 特殊情况可以照顾。
>   Tèshū qíngkuàng kẹ̌yǐ zhàogu.
>   We'll give consideration to special cases.
>
> 3 TRAD.
>   patronize (as a customer)

Answer (score 2):

安慰 "make somebody 'not sad'"

照顾 "take care of somebody"

The difference is quite literal in a sense.

(I'm Chinese, but not a grammar expert...)

Answer (score 1):

We usually use chatting to 安慰，such as some fell sad and we should speak something to him to make him happy, this action like 安慰。

Answer (score 0):

He's upset, so I comfort him.) 他生病了，我照顾他。(He's sick, so I took care of him.)[![

>
 [

> [image]

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwl9n.jpg)

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwl9n.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwl9n.jpg)